# Netsuite: Meta tags on shopping.ssp file for Suite Commerce Advanced

Tags: netsuite, meta-tags, suitecommerce

Problem Statement : On PDP page, we need to be able to include corresponding tags ( meta tags - which will allow us to include Image previews, custom URLs, etc. on Social Media ). With default functionality, we are not able to include Image previews or URLs while sharing.

Query Details :

We are using SCA's default feature to Share Product's details on Social Platform. SCA's and Open Graph Protocol's  Documentation says to get the product  title, description, image, url, will require meta tags on html page.

URL : http://yoursite/product/431

We have tried configuring all require meta tags and it is coming under  of element (to view this you need to open console and in Element tab under head tag), but We are not able to see Image and Description on Social Platform after sharing the product url. It only gives us product url.

If you view source on product details page, you will not see any configured meta tags there(og tags), we thought this could be the reason. Since, PDP comes under Shopping ssp, we tried adding hard coded meta tags in shopping.ssp file it self - In that case it works as expected.

Alos, We have found below SCA's site and looking at the 'View Source Code' it looks like they are using shopping.ssp file for og meta tags.

URL: http://www.newlifepatriot.com/S-NFHRV

Our query is - We will require actual product image, description, title to be included in Social Media Sharing, how we can get these tags propagated onto  shopping.ssp.  Or Is there any way get the meta tags working with the default functionality using some of the backend configuration or code overriding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for seodebug error by view-source:http://www.newlifepatriot.com/S-NFHRV?seodebug=T

Try to remove error on page, basically mmeta tag generation should not take more than 30 sec, If it is meta tag will not generat.